# Customise generated Slick SQL for debugging

Tags: scala, slick

I want to customise the SQL that Slick generates for a standard insert before it is sent to the DBMS, so that I can add extra DBMS-specific debugging options that Slick doesn't natively support. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the action level (i.e., with a `DBIO`), you can replace the SQL Slick will use via `overrideStatements`. Combined with `statements` to access the SQL Slick generates, that would give you a place to jump in and customize the SQL.

Bare in mind, you'll be working with `String`s with these two API calls.

A simple example would be:

```scala
val regularInsert = table += row

// Switching the generated SQL to all-caps is a terrible idea,
// and may not run in your database, but it will do as an example:
val modifiedSQL = regularInsert.statements.map(_.toUpperCase())


val modifiedInsert = regularInsert.overrideStatements(modifiedSQL)

// run modifiedInsert action as normal
```

The next step up from this would be to implement a custom database profile to override the way inserts are created to include debugging.
This is more involved: you'd want to extend the profile you're currently using, and dive into the Slick APIs to override various methods to change the insert behaviour. For example, you might start by exploring the existing [Postgres profile](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/PostgresProfile.scala) if that's the database you're using.

However, the above example can be applied per-insert as needed which may be enough for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a connection pool such as HikariCP, you can put a Java breakpoint on the `ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(String sql)` method, or the equivalent method in whatever connection pool library you are using. Then when the SQL of interest is about to be prepared by that method, use your debugger's "evaluate expression" functionality to modify/replace the value of `sql`.

This won't work if the library you are setting the breakpoint on is not open source, or for some other reason is compiled without debugging information.